# Password security for photo albums

Tags: php, security, passwords

Im making a album system, and you can have the option to activate passwordsecure to it, so you can make your own password to the album.. What would be the most appropiate to use to store this, should i make it md5/sha1 crypted, or store it directly normaly in the db like "123".. ?

Comment: What if your albums are managed by users who have passwords and they give their albums the same passwords as their accounts?

Comment: @BoltClock whats the problem by that? (dont know if i understood you correctly), if a user has a password and use that same password to his albums, yeah..then what? what is concering about that? thanks

Comment: If you store an album password in plain, that'll very likely be an attacker's first guess to his account.

Comment: Never ever store a plaintext password. Ever. Ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always store passwords in encrypted form and also append salt before encryption....

[**The Secure Way to Store Passwords with PHP:**](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/04/the-secure-way-to-store-passwords-with-php.html)

```
$password = 'ilovjenny84';
$salt = 'SHAKY SHARKY 333'; // some random string
$password_hash = sha1($salt.sha1($password.$salt)); // $password_hash = 4c3c8cbb4aa5de1c3ad9521501c6529506c6e5b4
```

Look at this article also:

[PHP encryption for the common man](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-encrypt/)

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by append salt before encryption? thanks

Comment: You mean hashed.  Never **ever** use a reversible encryption method.  Always use a one way hash.  And always use a strong salt.

Comment: Cant i use this to make the password: http://www.phpbin.net/x/1514527382 , is this good enough

Comment: @Karem: salt logic make it more difficult to recognize encrypted passwords when two users use same password and encrypt it with different salt strings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store it plaintext, that's a no-go. Use a function of the SHA-family (like SHA1 is).
Also, use a salt with your passwords.